#  Ignoring incoming data in TcpClient / NetworkStream

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, tcpclient

For communication with some third-party software, I need to establish an unidirectional connection over TCP. My software only needs to send data to the other side and never will read any data.
Currently I'm using the TcpClient. What would happen if there are incoming packets nonetheless and I never read them? Would they pile up somewhere and lead to some errors or the like? How would I configure the TcpClient to ignore or discard all incoming data?

The whole design is not exactly what I would do, but I can't change the other software and need to bear with this.

Some nice hints on the bits inside a TcpClient would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some of the data will be buffered, waiting for you to read it. Not sure how large the buffer size is, however. I don't think it will lead to errors immediately, but if the sender is expecting to be able to write, at some point the write may time out and the other party may choose to close the connection.

Comment: FYI, the buffer probably doesn't exist at the TcpClient level - it's probably pretty deep in the networking stack.

Comment: The other party will be able to send data even if the OPs receive buffer is full.

Comment: When the receiving party's buffer is full, I don't see how the sending party can logically transmit any more data. Someone has to store it, and it isn't going to be the routers. It seems logical to me that the sending party has to buffer it.

Comment: You mean that there should be a lot of "hey don't send me anymore data, I'm full" packets going all over the internet? I don't think so...

Comment: No, I'm not saying that's what happens. I'm just saying the sender participates in the buffering of data, and that the received has the right to limit the buffer or not buffer at all. I think the sender basically gets data from the receiver as to how to control flow.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will happen from your point of view. Data will be discarded.